# Half of My Kubernetes Cluster Is Never Used, Due to the Way Pods Are Scheduled

Tags: kubernetes, scheduler, topology

I have a Kubernetes cluster with 4 nodes and, ideally, my application should have 4 replicas, evenly distributed to each node. However, when pods are scheduled, they almost always end up on only two of the nodes, or if I'm very lucky, on 3 of the 4. My app as quite a bit of traffic and I would really want to use all the resources that I pay for.

I suspect the reason why this happens is that Kubernetes tries to schedule the new pods on the nodes that have the most available resources, which is nice as a concept, but it would be even nicer if it would reschedule the pods once the old nodes become available again.

What options do I have? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have lots of options!

First and foremost: [Pod Affinity and Anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity) to make sure your Pod prefer to be placed on a host that does not already have a Pod with the same label.

Second, you could set up [Pod Topology Spread Constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/). This is newer and a bit more advanced, but usually a better solution that simple anti-affinity.

Thirdly, you can pin your Pods to a specific node using a [NodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector).

Finally, you could write your own scheduler or modify the default scheduler settings, but that's a bit more advanced topic. Don't forget to always set your resource requests correctly, these should be set to a value that more or less encapsulates the usage during peak traffic, to make sure that a node has enough resources available to max out the Pod without interfering with other Pods.

Comment: Also make sure you are setting good resource requests, those matter a lot.

Comment: OK, I've heard about affinity before, but I did not think this would be the solution. Thanks a lot! I ended up adding the following to my spec:template:spec section of the deployment.yaml file:      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - myAppName
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"